# Multiple ajax request with promise in Angular based on array vlaues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, angular-promise

I am implementing multiple ajax calls in sequence in angular. What I want to achieve is working fine with `$.ajax` but when I implemented with angular where I'm using `$http` for server request, it's not working. I am wondering that both are returning promise object then why it's not working properly.

**Using $.ajax**

```
shoppingList.split(",").reduce(function(resultPromise, shoppingItem) {

    return resultPromise.then(function(result) {
        pro = $.ajax('/items/'+shoppingItem);
        return pro.then(function(res) {
            console.log(result);
            result.push(new Item(res.label,res.price));
            return result;
        });
    });
}, $.when([])).then(completeCallback);
```

See the working fiddle - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obkp6Lg0/6/)

**Using Angular $http**

```
function fetchDataDayWise(dateRanges,completeCallback) {
        return dateRanges.reduce(function(resultPromise, dt) {
            return resultPromise.then(function(resultData) {
                machinePromise = getData();
                return machinePromise.then(function(data) {
                    if(data && data.length > 0)
                    {
                        resultData = resultData.concat(data);
                    }
                    console.log(resultData);
                    return resultData;
                });
            });
        }, $.when([])).then(completeCallback);
    }

    var dateRanges = [1,2,3,4]

    function setData(data) {
        console.log("data",arguments);

    }
    fetchDataDayWise(dateRanges,setData);
```

See the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bpzQ9j?p=preview)

You can see in console. In JSFiddle, you will get array of items while in Angular plunkr it returns object. I guess it's promise object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Always post relevant code at SO. This is not expected from an experienced user.

Comment: @Satpal Sorry for delay, I was just modifying so bit late.

Comment: Agreed with above - I'm seeing this more and more, and ignoring more and more questions...

Answer (score 1):

In your service you use $http.get, this returns a promise which is the object you are seeing, to get your values from it you need to have (in your case):

```
deferred.resolve(data.data);
```

instead of

```
deferred.resolve(data);
```

Hope this helps.  If you have any more questions i'll be happy to answer them.

Update:

This isn't for your code exactly, but it will give you an example of how to achieve sequential calls.

`var prevPromise = $q.resolve();
     prevPromise = prevPromise.then(function() {
         this.someValue= value; //array of databases containing queryresults
         return this.function(req, res);
     }.bind(this));`

Comment: well, In angular service you can see I bind success method only so data will work. In case of .then method with $http, I need to have data.data. Still I tried with data.data, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your plnkr hope this will help

http://plnkr.co/edit/VWJMNU?p=preview

```
function fetchDataDayWise(dateRanges, compleCallback) {
      var arrPromise = [];

      dateRanges.reduce(function (dt) {
        arrPromise.push(getData());
      });

      $q.all(arrPromise).then(compleCallback);
    }
```

Comment: This will work but I want server call in sequence not at once. I want to update UI as soon as I am getting data and other calls will be running at the same time.

Comment: you do not want all request to comeback before rendering UI As soon single request comes you want to render UI.. am i right?

Comment: Also, I want callback function to be executed at last only. Not after every call complete.

Comment: Then if you want your callback should be called at all resolves, then how your controller will have data, if you are not calling your callback.

Comment: Check my code in plunkr. I'm calling service from controller only where I have callback then for each service call.